# Tweepy Paginator AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta'

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to print tweet data but I get an error that I can't fix. When I try and run the code in the docs I still get the same error. Is this a python 3.8 issue?

Code in docs:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, "Tweepy",
                                max_results=100).flatten(limit=250):
    print(tweet.id)
```

Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "scraper.py", line 34, in main
    for item in paginator:
  File "/Users/troy/Desktop/streamlit/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/pagination.py", line 100, in __next__
    self.previous_token = response.meta.get("previous_token")
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

My Code:

```
import tweepy
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd

# global tokens
api_key = os.environ.get('Twitter_API_Key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('Twitter_API_Secret')
access_token = os.environ.get('Twitter_Access_Token')
access_secret = os.environ.get('Twitter_Access_Secret')
bearer = os.environ.get('bearer_token')

def create_client():
    client = tweepy.Client( bearer_token=bearer,
                        return_type=requests.Response,
                        wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    return client

def create_paginator(authenticated_client):

    paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
        authenticated_client.search_recent_tweets,
        query='from:elonmusk',
        tweet_fields=['author_id', 'id', 'created_at'],
        max_results=100,
        limit=5)

    return paginator

def main():
    client = create_client()
    paginator = create_paginator(client)
    print(paginator)
    for item in paginator:
        print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I needed `.flatten()`. Don't know why but hey that's show business.

```
def create_paginator(authenticated_client, query):
    paginator = tweepy.Paginator(authenticated_client.search_recent_tweets, query=query,
                                  tweet_fields=['author_id', 'id', 'created_at'],max_results=10).flatten(limit=5)
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Don't know why it works, but it does.